# how to make interactive map on sphere in unity3d

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, unity3d

I am working on a **Unity3d** Project and want to show **world map** using **google** on a sphere Gameobject or Plane but actually the problem is Google provide static API which don't provide image greater then 640 x 640.
How can I get High defination interactive image or else solution. I heard about tiles but I didn't find it on Google Map.

How you will make map in Unity3d using any Map system like google or OSM. Or QGIS can provide any help in this regard>

Answer (score 1):

Even if OSM and Google raster maps rely on the similar technology (['slippymaps'](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map)) you need to decide which one you like to chose, as this influences the implementation.
Basically you cache and display that tiles of the map which will be visible on your current view. If you pan/zoom you load the next ones etc....

You might have a look at [Openlayers3 (JS)](http://openlayers.org/) or [Marble (C++)](https://marble.kde.org/) to get an idea how to project plain maps on a 3D globe. You might also want to contact the [3D OSM community](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_development).

Comment: is there any complete guide available ?

Comment: No, all the applications are custom projects